# Does the past participle or a adjective agree in plural forms for subject "on"?

Tags: pronoms, accord

[This page](https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/guides/z2h6tfr/revision/3) presents the following example sentences:

> So the perfect tense of *aller* (to go) is:
>
> - ......
> - on est **allé(e)(s)** - we went **`<-- what?`**
> - ......

I well understand the optional *e* because "we" can be feminine, but what's that *s* supposed to be?

I searched on the web but didn't find any reference about whether the adjective should agree in the plural form when the subject is *on* and the verb is *être*.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2018/02/08/37003-20180208ARTFIG00020-on-est-arrives-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php

> Lorsque le pronom qualifie «un sujet dont on ignore le sexe ou le
>   nombre», «des personnes indéterminées», l'usage veut que le participe
>   ait un genre non marqué. C'est-à-dire un masculin singulier. Pour être
>   correct, on préférera donc écrire: «On n'est pas sûr d'y arriver.»
>
> Toutefois -et c'est là le hic!- comme le précisent les sages, il
>   arrive parfois que le «on» puisse caractériser «telle ou telle
>   personne». Dans ces cas-là, alors il faudra faire l'accord en genre et
>   en nombre. Exemple: «On est allés ensemble faire les magasins», «On
>   est arrivés très tôt, en famille, à la piscine aujourd'hui».

Voir aussi :

http://www.academie-francaise.fr/pauvre

Comment: Ferais-tu le réponse en anglais? Je ne suis pas sûr que je puisse comprendre la français bien.

Comment: @iBugauxerreurs I will try to translate. For the time being see here https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/understanding-french-on-subject-pronoun

Comment: @iBugauxerreurs and here https://www.thoughtco.com/the-many-meanings-of-the-french-subject-pronoun-on-3572148

Answer (score 2):

*On* can have several roles in French.

1. It can be used to represent an indefinite person or group of persons. In that case, the agreement stays in masculine singular (*On* etymologically means *homme*).

> **On** apporte **son** manger.
>
> Dans ce pays, **on** est **autorisé** à dire ce qu'on pense.

2. It is used as a substitute to the first plural person conjugated verbs which have essentially disappeared in spoken French. In that case, the verb is still third person singular but the remaining agreements should follow the actual number and gender:

> Ne t'inquiètes pas, **on** apporte **notre** manger.
>
> **On** est **parties** ce matin à sept heures.

3. It can be used as a substitute of other persons, singular or plural and the agreement also usually matches the actual subject:

> Les cousines, **on** est **partantes** pour aller à la plage ?
>
> Alors les filles, **on** s'est **faites** belles aujourd'hui !

This alternative form is also accepted :

> Alors les filles, **on** s'est **fait** belles aujourd'hui !

Answer (score 0):

L'[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+arriv%C3%A9%2Con+est+arriv%C3%A9s%2Con+est+arriv%C3%A9es&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20arriv%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20arriv%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20arriv%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0) suivant montre que certains grammairiens et d'autres personnes sont en train d'essayer de changer la grammaire concernant ce pronom, qui ne s'est jamais accordé jusqu'à présent qu'au neutre singulier.

[on est venu](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+venu%2Con+est+venus%2Con+est+venues&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20venu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20venus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20venues%3B%2Cc0), [on est parti](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+parti%2C+on+est+partis%2C+on+est+parties&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20parti%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20partis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20parties%3B%2Cc0), [on est reconnu](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+reconnu%2Con+est+reconnus%2Con+est+reconnues&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20reconnu%3B%2Cc0), [on est appliqué](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+appliqu%C3%A9%2Con+est+appliqu%C3%A9s%2C+on+est+appliqu%C3%A9es&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20appliqu%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20est%20appliqu%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0), [on est averti](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+averti%2Con+est+avertis%2C+on+est+averties&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20averti%3B%2Cc0), [on est compris](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+compris%2Con+est+comprises&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20compris%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20est%20compris%3B%2Cc0), [on est étendus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+%C3%A9tendu%2Con+est+%C3%A9tendus%2C+on+est+%C3%A9tendues&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20%C3%A9tendu%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20est%20%C3%A9tendu%3B%2Cc0), [on est allé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+all%C3%A9%2Con+est+all%C3%A9s%2Con+est+all%C3%A9es&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20all%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20all%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20all%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20est%20all%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20all%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20all%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0)

Cela est confirmé par de multiples cas, comme ceux ci-dessus.

La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1708)
 conseille de faire l'accord de la façon suivante ;

> Le pronom indéfini on désigne souvent une personne ou un ensemble de personnes dont on ignore l’identité, un peu à la manière de quelqu’un, quiconque ou tout le monde. Dans ces emplois, le participe passé ou l’adjectif qui se rapporte au pronom on est invariable, c’est-à-dire au masculin et au singulier, puisqu’on ignore d’ordinaire le sexe et le nombre de personnes que le pronom on représente. L’accord peut cependant se faire au féminin si on représente une femme.
>
> Le pronom on peut aussi représenter une ou plusieurs personnes qui sont bien définies. On peut alors le remplacer par un pronom personnel (je, tu, nous, vous). Dans ces emplois, le participe passé ou l’adjectif qui s’y rapporte prend le genre et le nombre du sujet représenté par on. L’emploi de on pour désigner une ou plusieurs personnes bien définies est surtout fréquent à l’oral dans un registre familier. Dans un style soutenu, notamment à l’écrit, il est préférable d’utiliser le pronom personnel, le plus souvent nous, correspondant.